# MPMoviePlayerViewController notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotificationcenter

How to set notifications to MPMoviePlayerViewController? Is it the same as in MPMoviePlayerController?

Show example please

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The MPMoviePlayer**View**Controller is just a wrapper giving you controls to a MPMoviePlayerController.

`MPMoviePlayerViewController` has its own `MPMoviePlayerController` that sends all the notifications you need to work with it.

Listening to notifications is done as follows:

```
// Register for the playback finished notification
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self // the object listening / "observing" to the notification
    selector:@selector(myMovieFinishedCallback:) // method to call when the notification was pushed
    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification // notification the observer should listen to
    object:self.moviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer]; // the object that is passed to the method
```

There are a lot more notifications you can and should work with that are listed in the [`MPMoviePlayerController Class Reference`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html)

So basically, yes - You can use the same notifications as in `MPMoviePlayerController`